# "Failed to lock C:\ProgramData\bitmonero.daemon_lock"

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, error-log

I am trying to run monerod.  After a few weeks. Getting this error.

2016-Nov-04 15:45:51.273766 Initializing cryptonote protocol... 
2016-Nov-04 15:45:51.274768 Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2016-Nov-04 15:45:51.275771 Initializing p2p server...
2016-Nov-04 15:45:51.720954 Set limit-up to 2048 kB/s
2016-Nov-04 15:45:51.721957 Set limit-down to 8192 kB/s
2016-Nov-04 15:45:51.721957 Set limit-up to 2048 kB/s
2016-Nov-04 15:45:51.721957 Set limit-down to 8192 kB/s
2016-Nov-04 15:45:51.728975 Binding on 0.0.0.0:18080
2016-Nov-04 15:45:51.728975 Net service bound to 0.0.0.0:18080
2016-Nov-04 15:45:51.728975 Attempting to add IGD port mapping.
2016-Nov-04 15:45:52.882042 Added IGD port mapping.
2016-Nov-04 15:45:52.882042 P2p server initialized OK
2016-Nov-04 15:45:52.882042 Initializing core rpc server...
2016-Nov-04 15:45:52.882042 Binding on 127.0.0.1:18081
2016-Nov-04 15:45:52.883045 Core rpc server initialized OK on port: 18081
2016-Nov-04 15:45:52.883045 Initializing core...
2016-Nov-04 15:45:52.890063 **Failed to lock C:\ProgramData\bitmonero.daemon_lock**
2016-Nov-04 15:45:52.891066 **ERROR C:/msys64/DISTRIBUTION-BUILD/src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:271 Failed to lock "C:\ProgramData\bitmonero"**
2016-Nov-04 15:45:52.891066 Deinitializing rpc server...
2016-Nov-04 15:45:52.892069 Deinitializing p2p...
2016-Nov-04 15:45:52.902096 Deinitializing core...
2016-Nov-04 15:45:52.912122 Closing IO Service.
2016-Nov-04 15:45:52.912122 Failed to deinitialize core...
2016-Nov-04 15:45:52.913125 Deinitializing cryptonote_protocol...

Any idea whats causing it?

Comment: Can you add a little more detail?  The main question I have is whether you used a pre-built binary or whether you built it yourself. Also, it appears you're on Windows.  Please add which version of Windows. Also, when did you install or build it?  Please add these and other possibly relevant details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you were running it before and killed it uncleanly. Windows takes a few minutes to notice that the owner of a file lock has died, before it cleans up the lock.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a "Run As Administrator"  problem.

If you are running it by clicking monerod.exe from Windows, Right Click and select Run as Administrator.